# how to create a element that will switch to display:none/block when clicked on a button and display:none when when the screen is larger than 1023px

Tags: javascript

how can I change a div element that is opened(from display:none, to display block) by a click on a navigation button to closing it automatically when the media screen is min-width: 1023px?

Everytime I click on the navigation button the div with display="none" switch to display="block" but it stays on display block even though I make the screen larger.

I tried to put a function within a function but that did not work either

Comment: you have forgot to show us the code. Press the <> button and add the relevant code to create a snippet

Comment: You need [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) for [Click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) on a **button** and in your javascript, you can perform the thing of your desire using [DOM style Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp) and for screen dimensions, you can use [Screen Width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width)    Use these link, write some code, then if you stuck, then comeback SO will help you.

Comment: @LelioFaieta hey the last problem I got is getting the right return from my viewport size this is my code I tried a lot but I could not work it out with the right return of the viewport size. I always get a viewport size back that is 10 px or more wider than my screen size is. So I dont now what to because at this site they get my screen size(window.innerWidth) right.

Comment: static.lukew.com/stest.html

Comment: @LelioFaieta static.lukew.com/stest.html this site
I dont see the <> button
this is my code
  function myFunction() {
   lwidth =  window.innerWidth;
   lwidth1 = window.innerWidth;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width: " + lwidth;
  var x = document.getElementById("myresponsivemainnavcontainer");
  if (x.style.display === "none" && lwidth == lwidth1 ) {
   x.style.display = "block";
   alert(lwidth);
  } else {
   x.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
thankyou for taking your time

Comment: @NotABot Thankyou a lot went good I am only getting not the right return from my windws screen I have tried a lot but it did not work
 this is my code 
< 
myFunction() {
 lwidth = window.innerWidth;
 lwidth1 = window.innerWidth; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width: " + lwidth; var x = document.getElementById("myresponsivemainnavcontainer");
if (x.style.display === "none" && lwidth == lwidth1 ) { x.style.display = "block"; alert(lwidth); } else {
 x.style.display = "none";
 } 
} 
>